# php/sql- How do I use LIKE operator on variable to pull results from database?

Tags: php, mysql

As question said, I want to use the `LIKE` Operator so whenever user inputs something, like "M", it returns all database entries starting with "m" rather then anything named just "M". This is my code

```
$strSymbolName = @$_REQUEST["searchSymbol"];
//searchSymbol is the variable with user Input inside

if(!empty($strSymbolName))
{ // process the form
 // Establish dbserver connection and default database

$db = $objDBUtil->Open();
 // Run a Query to get company name

$query = "SELECT symSymbol, symName FROM symbols " .
 "WHERE symSymbol =" . $objDBUtil->DBQuotes($strSymbolName);
//Retrieves company symbol and name from database. Stores this in result

$result = $db->query($query);`
```

What I thought of doing was using the LIKE operator on the WHERE statement, so something like-

```
WHERE symSymbol LIKE = " . $objDBUtil->DBQuotes($strSymbolName);
```

But this didn't work...How would I apply the LIKE operator here?

Comment: `"LIKE %".$objDBUtil->DBQuotes($strSymbolName)."%"`

Comment: Get rid of the `=` sign after `LIKE` and then use `%` wildcard markers where appropriate.

Comment: I tried that line, replaced it with what I showed above, but my program isn't recognizing it (the line is gray)                                                                           "WHERE symSymbol "LIKE %".$objDBUtil->DBQuotes($strSymbolName)."%"

Answer (score 1):

```
$db = $objDBUtil->Open();

$param = $objDBUtil->DBQuotes($strSymbolName);

$query = "SELECT symSymbol, symName FROM symbols WHERE symSymbol LIKE '%$param%'";

$result = $db->query($query);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you also put in some explanation of what the code does and format it correctly please?

Comment: $db = $objDBUtil->Open();

$param = $objDBUtil->DBQuotes($strSymbolName);

$query = "SELECT symSymbol, symName FROM symbols WHERE symSymbol LIKE  '%$param%'  ";

$result = $db->query($query);

Comment: I meant in your answer. Format the code using the code tags and put in some explanation for users as well please

Answer (score 1):

just use LIKE query

```
$db = $objDBUtil->Open();
$query = "SELECT symSymbol, symName FROM symbols WHERE symSymbol LIKE '%$strSymbolName%'";
$result = $db->query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the `%` on the end of your variable like:

```
WHERE symSymbol LIKE " . $objDBUtil->DBQuotes($strSymbolName) . "%";
```

This will return anything starting with your variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search something that starts with "M", add a `%` after the value, and remove the `=` as it is not needed when using `LIKE`

```
$query = "SELECT symSymbol, symName FROM symbols WHERE symSymbol LIKE ".$objDBUtil->DBQuotes($strSymbolName)."%";
```

For more information about `LIKE`, check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp).

> WHERE CustomerName LIKE 'a%'        || Finds any values that starts with "a"
>
> WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%a'        || Finds any values that ends with "a"
>
> WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%or%'    || Finds any values that have "or" in any position
>
> WHERE CustomerName LIKE '_r%'       || Finds any values that have "r" in the second position
>
> WHERE CustomerName LIKE 'a_%_%' || Finds any values that starts with "a" and are at least 3 characters in length
>
> WHERE ContactName LIKE 'a%o'          || Finds any values that starts with "a" and ends with "o"

Answer (score 0):

Use the `%` wildcard after the string you want to look for.

```
$query = "SELECT symSymbol, symName FROM symbols WHERE symSymbol LIKE ".$objDBUtil->DBQuotes($strSymbolName)."%";
```

A bit more on the `%` and other wildcards: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Excerpt from above link:

> WHERE CustomerName LIKE 'a%'        || Finds any values that starts
>   with "a"
>
> WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%a'        || Finds any values that ends with
>   "a"
>
> WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%or%'    || Finds any values that have "or"
>   in any position
>
> WHERE CustomerName LIKE '_r%'       || Finds any values that have "r"
>   in the second position
>
> WHERE CustomerName LIKE 'a_%_%' || Finds any values that starts with
>   "a" and are at least 3 characters in length
>
> WHERE ContactName LIKE 'a%o'          || Finds any values that starts
>   with "a" and ends with "o"